# jQuery dropdown selected=selected in Safari does not work

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, safari, html-select

I have got a subscribe form with several tabs.
You can click backwards and forwards in this form.

For drop downs I use a jquery to preselect a previous choice, so people do not have to re-answer this specific question on clicking backwards.

This script works fine for Chrome and Firefox, however for Safari it does not work at all.
Somehow I just can't get this to work.

Can you please have a look at it and tell me what I am doing wrong?

the script:

```
if (repeat_visit !== '') {
    $('#repeatVisit').find('option').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() === repeat_visit) {
            $(this).attr('selected','selected');
        }
    });
}
```

The attribute is set to the option so it looks like:
    Yes

I can see this does happen, but it seems that Safari does not change the page when the selected attribute is added after the page load. So somehow I need to trigger this change event.

Comment: can you create fiddle for same?

Comment: have you tried just using $('#repeatVisit').val(repeat_visit);

Comment: No JSfiddle And I can try to set the value like that thanks!

Comment: Nope setting the value does not work either. I think it has more to do with Safari and HTML then with jQuery somehow

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I found the answer!

You can use .prop('selected', true) in stead off attr('selected','selected');

Comment: Thanks! this seems to fix the issue.

Comment: Indeed, chrome and firefox still perform well with `.attr('selected')`, safari needs `.prop('selected')` (this was blocking me from using select2 with safari 11+)

Comment: Safari..... :@, I had used that but the issue is to deselect explicitly the previously selected option too.

Comment: this answer is still saving developers all these years later! I was troubleshooting for about six hours. Zeroing in on the culprit.. getting closer... closer... then it came down to the select box. I did a google search and *bam* here I am! Thanks! I hope you've been getting a lot of points for this over the years. It certainly saved me today!

Answer (score 2):

The following function works in current Safari, Safari Mobile, Chrome, Edge, and Firefox as of this writing.

This handles the issue where the .prop calls MUST be done before the .attr calls or the entire thing is ignored, and the redraw issue in firefox.

```
    function updateSelect(selectname, value){
        $('select[name="'+selectname+'"] option').prop('selected',false);
        $('select[name="'+selectname+'"] option').removeAttr('selected');
        $('select[name="'+selectname+'"] option[value="'+value+'"]').prop('selected',true);
        $('select[name="'+selectname+'"] option[value="'+value+'"]').attr('selected','selected');
        $('select[name="'+selectname+'"]').val(value).change();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just change DOM elements with the `.prepend()` function to add the option selected to first element inside select.

```
selectElement.children[i].setAttribute("selected", true);
selectElement.prepend(selectElement.children[i]);
```